# Unable to round of vdatatable values to 8 decimal places in VUE3

Tags: vuejs3, vuetify.js, vite, vuetifyjs3

I am porting an old vue2 project to vue3 the project used Math.round function to round off current market data, i.e bids and asks to 8 decimal places. The function works fine with the old version however in the newer version it does not work and I get very long decimal values. I have tried something like this but it does not work.

```
<template v-slot:item.price="{ item }">
                {{ roundedPrice(item.price) }}
              </template>

              <template v-slot:item.price2="{ item }">
                {{ roundedPrice(item.price) }}
  <!-- Remaining code -->

<!--
better implementation handled in parent component on load of orders, then promise to set flag
                <v-chip v-if="hasMyOrder(item.price)" color="purple" dark>me</v-chip>
-->
                <v-chip v-if="item.myOrder" x-small color="purple" dark>*</v-chip>
              </template> 

              <template v-slot:item.maxvolume="{ item }">
                {{ roundedPrice(item.maxvolume) }}
              </template>

              <template v-slot:item.relamount="{ item }">
                {{ roundedPrice(item.price * item.maxvolume) }}
              </template>
```

The following is my roundedPrice method defined in my script:

```
computed: {
    roundedPrice() {
      return (price) => {
        return Number((Math.round(price * 1e8) / 1e8).toFixed(8));
      };
    }
  },
```

You can checkout the live project here and see the  AtomicDexOrderbook component which is the VDATABLE with market orders against the pair. The headings are a bit messed up as well.

http://v3dev.komodefi.com:17077/traderview/RICK/MORTY

This is my complete [code](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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):

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax for `v-data-table` slots has changed.  A lot has changed between Vuetify 2 and Vuetify 3 actually.  You will want to thoroughly review the [Vuetify 3 documentation](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables/basics/#item) any time you have an issue with the upgrade process.  Assume nothing is the same and always confirm whether the syntax of your old Vuetify 2 code is still documented, or if it has changed in Vuetify 3.

The new slot syntax for your price column should be like this:

```html
<template v-slot:item.price="{ item }">
  {{ roundedPrice(item.columns.price) }}
</template>
```

All of your slots that use `item.columnName` should be replaced with `item.columns.columnName`

The computed property itself is fine. The `Math` object is vanilla JavaScript, so nothing Vue or Vuetify related could affect it's calculation.

[working Vue Playground example](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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)

Comment: Still does not work I have updated my question with link to my complete code

Comment: You have two different `computed` properties on your component, you need to combine them into one.  Then in your `asksHeaders` array, there is no `value` property anymore, it's been replaced with `key`.  Those two things should at least get the UI displaying the rounded numbers.  My playground link in my answer has been updated.  There is some other broken code I commented out to get working in the playground, but the important bits are working.  The mock data I took from the API calls of your site.  I haven't worked out why some are giving "NaN", probably just bad data or wrong data format.

Comment: Perfecto works absolutely fine now and moreover, the heading names do appear now as well for the pair we are on. One question how do I disable pagination?